# Making a small application that check whether the string contain url or not

Tags: javascript, function

I am making a small application that checks whether the values from textarea contain URLs or not.

Here is my code:

```
let text = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value
let urls= text.toLowerCase().split(' ').filter(check)
function check(str){
                return str.startsWith('www.');
                return str.startsWith("http");
            }
console.log(urls)
//It will only check the value starts with 'www.' and won't check value starts with 'http'.
```

When I switch the sequence and put the `return str.startsWith("http");` at first, it will not check the value starts with 'www.' . Although it is not a big problem and i could define another function, i am just curious why doesn't that work and is there some ways that i could do it in just one function or just one single-line.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: With `return` you exit the function right away. You need to use `if` / `else` statements.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for the [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR). Use only a single `return` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Just added OR operator.

Important note: This is not a proper way to check if a string is valid URL or not. You have to check http(s)://,  dot(.) , domain extension, spaces and maybe more.

```js
let text = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value
let urls = text.toLowerCase().split(' ').filter(check)

function check(str) {
  if (str.startsWith('www.') || str.startsWith("http"))
    return str;
}
console.log(urls)
```

Comment: It works pretty well, but is there some ways that i could insert an array to check. Like this: `let url = ['http','www','htttps']; if (str.startsWith(url)){}; `I know it doesn't work, is there someway that i could use array to do it without using for loop. Thank you so much for taking time answering my question.

Comment: Yes, you can easily check using the array. Just loop through the array and check the condition.

Comment: So i must use the for loop?

Comment: Yes,

function check(str) {

  for(let urlItem of url) {
    if (str.startsWith(urlItem))
    return str;
  }
}

Comment: You are welcome. In this case there is nothing wrong using a loop. It's time complexity is O(n). To be honest time complexity does not matter when there are only few items in a array. If you are satisfied with the answer please mark the answer as "accepted".